# Trying to understand how to count with more than 1 group of balls

Tags: combinatorics

Let us assume that we have 5 balls(blacks have letters: a, b, c, and whites are d and e).

How many possibilities do we have for taking 1 black and 1 white(no replacement, order is important)? I would say $3\times 2\times 2!$, where the 2! is there since we could take (3b,2w) or (2w, 3b).

How many possibilities do we have for taking 1 black and 2 white(no replacement, order is important)? I would say $3\times 2\times 1 \times \frac{3!}{2!}$, since we have (3b,2w,1w) or (3b,1w,2w) as the same, but different from (2w,3b,1w) for example, and so we divide by $2!$.

How many possibilities do we have for taking 1 black and 2 white(no replacement, order is not important)? I think the answer is supposed to be $\frac{3}{1!} \times \frac{2\times 1}{2!}=C^3_1C^2_2$. The $3!$ disappeared since now we have (3b,2w,1w), (1w,3b,2w), (2w,1w,3b) as the same, for example, and so had to divide by $3!$ .

Edit: Now we have 30 balls:  7 blacks, 3 whites, 15 yellows, 5 greens.

Number of possibilities, in 5 draws, of 2b, 3y (no replacement, order important)? $\frac{7\times 6}{2!}\times \frac{15 \times 14 \times 13}{3!} \times 5! $

Number of possibilities, in 5 draws, of 2b, 3y (no replacement, order isn't important)? $\frac{7\times 6}{2!}\times \frac{15 \times 14 \times 13}{3!}=C^7_1 C^{15}_3 $

Number of possibilities, in 6 draws, of 2b, 3y,1g (no replacement, order is important)? $\frac{7\times 6}{2!}\times \frac{15 \times 14\times 13}{3!} \times\frac{5}{1!}\times 6! $

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: You have a lot of "division by symmetry" appearing in your attempts.  The general consensus on those sort of arguments is that they are less elegant and cause more confusion than approaches which avoid division by symmetry and so should be avoided.  For the second for instance, rather than saying "multiply by $\frac{3!}{2!}$" corresponding to the $3!$ ways of arranging all three if they were distinct and dividing by $2!$ for symmetry of two of them looking the same you could/should instead just say "multiply by $3$" which is in reference just to picking which of the three positions was black.

Comment: As you have already named them, I think it's better to use their names e.g., $ADE$, $EAD$, $DEA$, are same instead of (3b,2w,1w), (1w,3b,2w), (2w,1w,3b) are same. This should eliminate most of your confusion.

Comment: That said, your answers for the all of these appear correct, though it took me multiple times reading the last thinking it was wrong due to the division by symmetry arguments appearing where I didn't expect and I worry that it may have been a coincidence that they were correct and that if the numbers of each type of ball were changed that the approach might not have been correct.  I would have preferred "pick which location(s) used for black, from left to right which black ball in black position(s), from left to right which white ball in white position(s)" giving $3\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2=36$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the comments. Could you please give me an example of when you this reasoning by symmetry may be confusing? 

I'll edit the question, and add a more complex example, so that you can tell me if it was coincidence or not.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. an example of when *not* to use "division by symmetry" but beginning students often make the mistake anyways?  The number of distinct 2-letter words that can be made from the letters in `APPLE`.  Students might have accidentally said it was $\frac{5\cdot 4}{2!}=10$ but it was in fact $4\cdot 3 + 1=13$.  The mistake is made more obvious when asking for the number of distinct 2-letter words to be made from letters in `ABBBBBBB`, we can clearly count there are only $3$ (*AB, BA, BB*) but the incorrect argument might have lead to a non-integer.

Comment: I have not checked the other bonus questions in great detail, but your final answer there appears to be incorrect only due to a typographical error.  You should have had $\frac{7\cdot 6}{2!}\times\frac{15\times14\times 13}{3!}\times 5\times 6!$, you missed some things on the numerators.  I can see your logic more clearly now however and your answer could be adjusted simply by moving all the denominators to the final term and describing that as a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Comment: In my opinion, enumeration problems like this require a *moderately* sophisticated intuition.  This can be a *catch-22*, because the way to develop your intuition around problems like these is to attack them.  Given that, if I were new to combinatorics, I would try to create a general formula and apply it to the case of 3-black, 2-white.  Then, I would **manually count** to verify the formula.  Then I would *rinse-and-repeat* with (for example) 5-black, 3-white.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then I would again rinse-and-repeat with 7-black, 4 white.  This way, I would try to develop my intuition **first** before placing confidence in a formula that I developed.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your input! ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "...since we have (3b,2w,1w) or (3b,1w,2w) as the same, but different from (2w,3b,1w) for example, and so we divide by $2!$." This appears at the end of your solution to problem #2, in which it is stated that "order is important". If order is important, then in what sense are (3b,2w,1w) and (3b,1w,2w) the same?

Comment: @WillOrrick without looking at the letters (b,w,w) is the same as (b,w,w). But we were counting before as if they were different. (the number refer to the amount of letters we can choose from)

Comment: I think you meant "without looking at the numbers". If so, then your reasoning is identical to what's in my answer. Since my answer doesn't  seem to add anything to your existing understanding, I will delete it, which might increase your chances of getting a more helpful answer. Also, I don't see that your post contains a question, so it might be good to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: @WillOrrick I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clarified in comments that when you said,

> ...we have (3b,2w,1w) or (3b,1w,2w) as the same, but different from (2w,3b,1w) for example, and so we divide by $2!$,

you meant that the color labels, *BWW*, are the same for the first two, but different for the last one, *WBW*. I agree with all your answers, and I agree, if I understand you correctly, that you divide by $2!$ because *W* appears twice as a color label.

One observation: when you write

> number of possibilities, in 5 draws, of 2b, 3y (no replacement, order important)? $\frac{7×6}{2!}×\frac{15×14×13}{3!}×5!$,

we can interpret this as $\binom{7}{2}\binom{15}{3}\cdot5!$, or as the number of ways of carrying out the process

1. choose $2$ black balls;
2. choose $3$ yellow balls;
3. arrange the $5$ selected balls in some order.

An alternative expression is
$$
\frac{5!}{2!\,3!}\times(7\cdot2)\times(15\cdot14\cdot13),
$$
which can be interpreted as $\binom{5}{2,3}P(7,2)P(15,3)$, or the number of ways of carrying out the process

1. label $5$ slots with color labels *B*, *B*, *Y*, *Y*, *Y*;
2. select and arrange balls in the *B* slots;
3. select and arrange balls in the *Y* slots.

Interestingly, the second method can be applied to the situation where the balls are replaced. In this case you get
$$
\frac{5!}{2!\,3!}\times7^2\times15^3.
$$
This is similar to a problem that was in [an earlier version of your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3839903/7).

**Added in response to comment:** I regard it as a mistake to say that you divide by $2!$ to consider $(a,d,e)$ and $(a,e,d)$ the same. There are two ways to think about what the $2!$ is really for, depending on which of the two process above you are using.

If you are using the first process, there are $\frac{3}{1}$ sets containing one black ball, $\frac{2\cdot1}{2!}$ sets containing two white balls (there's your division by $2!$), and $3!$ ways of arranging the elements of a three-element set formed by taking the union of a set of one black ball and a set of two white balls. When you divide by $3!$ to go to the unordered version of the problem, you are simply undoing the final arrangement step. You could say that you divided by $2!$ because the **sets** $\{d,e\}$ and $\{e,d\}$ are the same set, and **not** because we want the **ordered triples** $(a,d,e)$ and $(a,e,d)$ to be considered the same. (Dividing by $3!$ takes care of the latter.)

If you are using the second process, there are $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways to put the color labels *B*, *W*, *W* on the slots (there's your division by $2!$), $3$ ways to put a black ball in the *B* slot, and $2\cdot1$ ways to put white balls in the two *W* slots. To do the unordered version of the problem, you divide by $3!$ to turn the number of ordered triples into the number of sets. You could say that you divided by $2!$ because the color labelings *BWW* and *BWW* are the same labeling. (Normally there are $3!$ permutations of three labels, but when two of the labels are identical, $3!$ overcounts the true number of permutations by a factor of $2!$.)

Comment: Will, I've been thinking over this problem... Somehow, I'm now confused over 1 detail. How come, when order is not important, we take out the $n!$ ($n=r_1+...+r_m$) but leave there the $r_i !$? It seems that we are dividing too much. For the 1st example, I said I divided by $3!$ because I wanted to consider $(a,d,e), (d,a,e), (a,e,d), (e,d,a) (d,e,a), (e,a,d)$ to be the same... However, I already divide by $2!$ to consider $(a,d,e),(a,e,d)$ the same...

Comment: My response was too long for a comment, so I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I think I understand it now ;) ;)